# No setter/field, trying to get data from firebase realtime database into textfields within my profileactivity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

> W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mobile found on class com.example.estateagentmapp.model.User (fields/setters are case sensitive!)

I had gotten this problem but not anymore.

I am using this to try and pull data from my firebase real-time database. But, I am unable to populate my text fields with it. what am I doing wrong?

here is the code I am doing it with and my user model. how do I fill in those textfields?

```
private fun getUserInfo() {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val uidRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
    val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
            user?.firstName == fname.toString()
            user?.lastName == lname.toString()
            user?.email == email.toString()
            user?.mobile == mobile.toString()
            user?.dateOfBirth == dob.toString()

        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("error", databaseError.message)

        }

    }
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
}
```

my model

```
data class User(val uid: String? = "",
                val firstName:String = "",
                val lastName:String = "",
                val mobile:String ="",
                val dateOfBirth:String ="",
                val email:String = "",
                val type: String = ""
) {
    constructor() : this("", "", "", "", "", "", "")
}
```

My realtime db is like this

```
user
      --uid
           --firstName
           --secondName
           --mobileName
           --dateOfBirth
           --email
           --type
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields in the database must have the same name as the fields in the model class, therefore you need to change `mobileName` to `mobile` in your realtime database.